# :Sequelize how set returned data order

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, sequelize.js

I've issues set the returned data order of a findAll query with limit and offset, i'm using example code found in the documentation: `order: 'group DESC'` but it throw an error saying:

```
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "group": syntax error
```

Here is the complete function.

```
A_Model.findAll({
     offset:req.query.page * req.query.rows - req.query.rows,
     limit :req.query.rows // TODO: Of course, I put the trailing comma here ;)
     // TODO: order: 'group DESC'
    })
.success(function (docs) {
    response_from_server.records = count;
    response_from_server.page = req.query.page;
    response_from_server.total = Math.ceil(count / req.query.rows);
    response_from_server.rows = [];

    for (item in docs) {
        response_from_server.rows.push({
            id  :docs[item].id,
            cell:[
                docs[item].group,
                docs[item].description,
                docs[item].path,
                docs[item].value
            ]
        });
    }

    // Return the gathered data.
    res.json(response_from_server);
})
.error(function (error) {       
    logger.log('error', error);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An SQL `group by` needs to define an aggregate function to group by.  It appears you haven't defined one.  Not sure if node.js even has that capability to do aggregates and group-by's.

Comment: @EricLeschinski: Thanks for your comment. I recently shifted from `mongodb` to `SQLite` and really know very little about `SQL`. Can you show me an example?

Comment: @EricLeschinski: Just noted: `group` is a column in the database. Maybe it is a reserved word?

Comment: In SQL, a 'group by' cannot stand alone.  It must have an aggregate function, for example, averaging the price by group.  Without doing an aggregation operation, grouping it makes no sense.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @EricLeschinski: What I really want is not grouping but order by a variable named `group`.

Comment: This functionality is achieved by the SQL "Order by" syntax.  In node.js there is a 'sort()' method, but that might be less efficient than getting it directly from the database in order.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: @EricLeschinski: Thanks. Do you know a way to make it work with Sequelize not SQL itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "order"-string you give to the findAll method is not parsed in Sequelize, only escaped to prevent SQL-injections. "group" is a reserved keyword in <del>most</del> *some* SQL-dialects, so the query fails to run.

To make it work simply put the "group" column into `'s, like this:

```
A_Model.findAll({
 offset:req.query.page * req.query.rows - req.query.rows,
 limit :req.query.rows,
 order: '`group` DESC'
})
```

Comment: Tried it in PostgreSQL and it should be `order: 'group DESC'` i.e. without the backquotes.